# instalacion oracle sin archivos

Tags: oracle

Estuve instalando **oracle**, pero al final no tengo este archivo, saben donde lo encuentro?

> `Error al llamar al destino 'links proc gen_pcscfg procob' del archivo
>   make '/u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/ins_precomp.mk'

Answer (score 0):

Luego de leer una información similar en **Fedora** instale el paquete:

> sudo apt install libjson-xs-perl

Con esto funcionò.